# Dynamic buttons (click) with custom logic in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some buttons that I store in DB.

But I don't know how to work with `(click)`

For example, I have a button "Close" that on click sets a boolean to false `isVisible = false`

**Model:**

```
export interface Button {
    label: string;
    class: string;
    iconClass: string;
    doJob: any;
}
```

**Template:**

```
<p-footer *ngIf="hasPopupButtons()">
    <a (click)="doStuff(button.doJob)" *ngFor="let button of Buttons" [ngClass]="button.class"><i
            [ngClass]="button.iconClass"></i>{{button.label}}</a>
</p-footer>
```

**Click function:**

```
doStuff(dostuff: any) {
    //??
}
```

How can I do this in a elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the property `doJob` as a `function which you want to call

```
 let button = {
        label: "Your Label";
        class: "your-class",
        iconClass: "your-icon-class,
        doJob: () => this.doStuff('doStuff')
 }
```

Template:

```
<a (click)="button.doJob()" *ngFor="let button of Buttons" [ngClass]="button.class"><i
            [ngClass]="button.iconClass"></i>{{button.label}}</a>
```